# An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in WebApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, exception, controller

I keep getting this exception from time to time whenever I try to run my web app: 
An exception of type "System.AggregateException' occurred in WebApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code"

The exception is triggered by the catch clause in the following code:

```
      public static IEnumerable<Airport> GetAirports(string url)
    {
        IEnumerable<Airport> airports = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        // write some code that retrieves the content from the url, and 
        // convert it to a list of airports.
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
      // by calling .Result you are performing a synchronous call
      var responseContent = response.Content;

      // by calling .Result you are synchronously reading the result

      string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      airports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Airport>>
                 (responseString);

            }
        }
        return airports;
    }
```

Comment: why a catch with a throw???? For that, don't use try/catch at all...

Comment: Also, an aggregate exception will have inner exceptions, look at those as there will be the real error message.

Comment: Check your inner exception, something like detailed message may hidden beneath it. I suspected the deserialization process throwing unhandled exception.